# Code Composer Studio: Imported driverlib project won't build lib

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, texas-instruments, code-composer

I'm trying to test a C2000 card by importing the "systick_ex1_interrupt" example from C2000Ware but when I tried to build it I got the following error:

> "gmake: *** No rule to make target '/driverlib/f2838x/driverlib_cm/ccs/Debug/driverlib_cm.lib', needed by 'all'

I kind of expected an example project to build without hassle but apparently I was mistaken and I haven't been able to find much to help me online

The project seems to know where the files required for the lib are since I'm able to find them in the project explorer but it just won't compile the driverlib_cm.lib file

Anyone knows anything ?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when some predefined variables are not set correctly. Make sure the paths to the libraries are correctly configured. For more details have a look at the [TI documentation](https://software-dl.ti.com/ccs/esd/documents/ccs_portable-projects.html#variables).